# Move UIView inside other UIView with addSubview

Tags: swift

I have `UIImageView` and I would like to align it to the right. But I'm trying to start with just moving:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "icon_delete"))

var rect = imageView.frame
rect.origin.x += 100
imageView.frame = rect

photosViewController.overlayView.bottomStackContainer.addSubview(imageView)
```

But seems it's not working and the image was setted to the left side:

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: Is `bottomStackContainer` a `UIStackView`?

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio no, its `AXStackableViewContainer`, which is `UIView` it's `AXPhotoViewer` library

Answer (score 0):

Try to use autolayout anchors

```
imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomStackContainer.leadingAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
```

Is **bottomStackContainer** a stackView? You should add arranged subviews by .addArrangedSubview() method then.

Comment: no, its `AXStackableViewContainer`, which is `UIView` it's `AXPhotoViewer` library

Comment: try to use anchors instead of frame manipulation, autolayout override manual frame changes

Comment: Yes, because this library also use some constraints. You can add two images, you icon, and transparent image with width 100 pixels. Or edit your icon, add transparent part 100px to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Try to redraw the view by using `setNeedsDisplay()` method.

Reference: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-force-a-uiview-to-redraw-setneedsdisplay

Answer (score 0):

First, assuming that:

```
photosViewController.overlayView.bottomStackContainer
```

is a view (which I'm calling containingView in my snippet), try something like:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "icon_delete"))
containingView.addSubview(imageView)

imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
containingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containingView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

If you need to move your image left away from the trailing edge, you can:

```
imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containingView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
```

or however far you need to move it.
Note: You'll get a runtime error if you forget to set the autoresizing mask to false on both views.